# Doctrine - ManyToMany with extra uniqueConstraints

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, unique-constraint

I'm trying to build a ManyToMany association between two classes, with a additional constraint on a field...

I have two classes A and B :

A can have many B and B can have many A.
This works well and generate a join table A_B :

```
class A
{
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="list_a") */
    private Collection $list_b;
}
class B
{
    private $id;
    private $type;

   /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="A", mappedBy="list_b") */
   private Collection $list_a;
}


CREATE TABLE A_B(
   a_id INT NOT NULL,
   b_id INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(a_id, b_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE A_B ADD FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A(id);
ALTER TABLE A_B ADD FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B(id);
```

Now, what I want is assert that A cannot have multiple B with the same $type and add something like that in the join table :

```
ALTER TABLE A_B ADD FOREIGN KEY (b_type) REFERENCES B(type);
ALTER TABLE A_B ADD uc_type UNIQUE (a_id, b_type);
```

So I wonder if it's possible with doctrine annotation and without having to create a third Class ?

Thanks

Comment: You have defined a ManyToMany association by adding a field in both associated entities right? If you follow that way, its the correct way to create ManyToMany association with no extra fields. If you want extra fields, well, the easy way is create a separate entity and create the foreign key to the other entities, and create the extra fields inside.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's what I think too ... I hope I missed a doctrine annotation that would allow me to do something like:
`/** 
*  @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="list_a") 
*  @JoinTable(name="A_B", 
*  ..... uniqueConstraint={ A(id), B(type) }
*/`